# Confused about hibernate in spring mvc

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i'm very new in spring mvc and struggling with hibernate now. I can extract data from ms sql server but the length of string is always to set maximum to field (add duplicate backspace character i think).
my Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "Username", length = 10)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

   //getter setter
    
}
```

My controller

```
@Controller
public class HibernateController {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

    @GetMapping("/getu")
    public String getUser() {
        List<Account> list = getList();
        for (Account account : list) {
            System.out.println("name: " + account.getUsername());
            System.out.println("nameLength: " + account.getUsername().length());
            System.out.println("pass: " + account.getPassword());

        }
        return "index";
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Account> getList() {
        Session session = getSession();
        String hql = "FROM Account";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        return query.list();
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

This is my table just have field username(nvarchar100) and password(nvarchar100)
Instead of having length of string exact the length for example "david" length is 5. My output when print account.getUsername().length() always is 100. Please help me with it

Comment: It looks like the fields actually stored in the database has been filled with trailing spaces. You can remove it with trim() method of String.

Comment: @Mar-Z i don't think it's the cause of problem, i also tried change the varlue of nvarchar in database like nvarchar(5) instead of nvarchar(100) and the result alway the maximum number of character in  this case the output will be 5

Comment: @Mar-Z Tks u man, it seem i'v found problems, its all about db, in db nchar type will automatically add space to fit length, when i use varchar instead every just go alright

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone that commented in this post. I've found the problem. The issue was caused by data type of database. nchar type is fixed length so when you insert data , the database will automatically add a number of space characters to fit in. For solution, just use varchar or nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Use @Size annotation instead of length. It will work

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Username")
    @Size(max = 10)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;

        // getters and setters
    }
```

If it still not works then please use

```java
@Column(length = 10)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer(
        read = "trim(my_column)",
        write = "trim(?)"
    )
    private String myColumn;
```

Comment: it's weird that i have tried many solution but it always give me the length of maximum length i set for nvarchar in sql server, if i change in database i will change too